# jQuery Ajax to asp.net asmx web service throws Request format is invalid: application/json

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery

I have jquery call an asp.net webservice with an integer.
On our legaacy application which was ported to .net 4.0 I cannot get this call to work.
I can call a method which has no parameters but sending data to the web method returns the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: application/json; charset=UTF-8. 
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters() 
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

I created exactly the same code in a blank project and it worked fine. I couldnt see anything in the web.config that the blank project added that would make a difference.

the Jquery Code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/WebService1.asmx/Test",
    data: JSON.stringify({"code": 1234}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

My Web Service Code

```
<ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class WebService1
    Inherits WebService

    <WebMethod()>
    Public Function Test(ByVal code As Integer) As String
        Return "success"
    End Function

    <WebMethod()>
    Public Function Hello() As String
        Return "hello"
    End Function    
End Class
```

Web Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>  
    <appSettings>
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
        <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" lockItem="true" />
        <trace enabled="false" pageOutput="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="true"/>

        <httpModules>
        </httpModules>
        <compilation debug="true" strict="true" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">

        </compilation>
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
        </pages>

        <authentication mode="Forms">

        <httpHandlers>     
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>

    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
    </handlers>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" > 
    </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you post your web.config file? I know where the problem is, just need a confirmation before I post the answer.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I have added the web.config but have removed sensitive details

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DOH, I was working in the wrong web.config.

Like a lot of questions on SO the solution was to add the following.

```
<system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem. But can you explain what it does. In my case it is specific to one machine. Any idea What could be the reason? And what could be the solution if I do not want to change my config file as it works fine on other machine.

Comment: Glad you were working in wrong web.config and posted question and answer. This saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @Akie I'm also not sure, but what I can tell you is ScriptHandlerFactory will add your WebServices to your JavaScript code as references at compile time. This means you are able to call directly to the WebMethods in your WebServices, via the syntax `namespace.class.method` in JavaScript. However, this is where I'm confused, so I can't give any answers about it.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and ending up running this command...

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Note that you will need your command prompt in Administrator mode for it to work.