# Webservice throws 500 error from AJAX, but not when called directly

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, web-services

I have an ASP.net application that's making a jQuery AJAX call to a VB.net webservice that lives **in the same directory**. On our test box, everything works beautifully. In production, if I go to the webservice's test form, I can retrieve data. The AJAX call, however, results in a 500 error. Here's the AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "webservice.asmx/Action",
    data: "{'SearchString':'" + request.term + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (res) {
        alert("Success");            
    },
    error: function () {
    alert("Fail");
    }
});
```

I've tried:

1. Fiddling with the format of the data parameter in that call
2. Setting the response format of the webservice ([ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)])
3. Added this to the Web.Config:

.

```
<webServices>
     <protocols>
         <add name="HttpSoap" />
         <add name="HttpGet" />
         <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
</webServices>
```

All has been for naught. This ONLY fails when being called from this function, and only on our production box. It works fine if I directly load the action from the .asmx page's form.

My thought is that there must be a configuration difference between our test and production servers, but I can't find one that would be of any consequence. Besides, what kind of configuration would cause it to not work when being called one way, but not another, when the server handles them the same way?

Has anyone encountered a similar problem that they've resolved?

Comment: What do your server logs say?

Comment: Ah, of course. Sorry:

`Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/Action'.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
 ...`

Comment: It's the same error you'd get it you went to the action URL without posting data. However, the request **should** be a POST and sending data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to track the error down to:

```
Request format is invalid: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Some research led me to this answer on another StackOverflow question: [the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992139/jquery-ajax-to-asp-net-asmx-web-service-throws-request-format-is-invalid-applic)

All is now well.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the following:

1. Add the follwoing inside the `<webServices>` section (which is inside the `<system.web>` section):

   ```
   <protocols>
       <add name="HttpGet"/><add name="HttpPost"/>
   </protocols>
   ```
2. Add the following to the `<handlers>` section (inside `<system.webServer>` of the `<configuration>` section) of your web.config (as mentioned in [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1649926.aspx?asmx+Request+format+is+invalid+NET+4+0+Integrated+Pipeline) forum):

   ```
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" 
    preCondition="integratedMode" 
    type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions,  
    Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" 
    preCondition="integratedMode" 
    type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, 
    System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
   ```

In my case, this fixed the issue. I had to add both steps 1. and 2., one alone did not help.