# AngularJS calling a rest service with parameter raises syntax error

Tags: angularjs, post, parameters

I have a .net web service containg two methods getUserTasks & getAllTasks(noOfDays) both return valid Json Data. Have verified it with JSONLINT.

```js
var app = angular.module('tasksApp', []);

app.controller('taskController', function($scope, $http, taskGroupFactory) {
  $scope.LoadTasks = function(taskFilter, dateFilter) {
    console.log(taskFilter + '-' + dateFilter);
    if (taskFilter == 'Self') {
      $scope.enableFilters = true;
      //$scope.taskGroups = taskGroupFactory.getUserTasks();
      var getUTasks = taskGroupFactory.getUserTasks();
      getUTasks.then(
        function(tasks) {
          console.log("success");
          $scope.taskGroups = tasks.data;
        }, function(errorData) {
          console.log("Error: " + errorData);
        });

    };

    if (taskFilter == 'All') {
      $scope.enableFilters = false;
      var getAllTasks = taskGroupFactory.getAllUserTasks(dateFilter);
      getAllTasks.then(
        function(tasks) {
          console.log("success");
          $scope.taskGroups = tasks.data;
        }, function(errorData) {
          console.log("Error: " + errorData);
        });
      //$scope.taskGroups = taskGroupFactory.getAllUserTasks(dateFilter);
      //            $scope.taskGroups = taskGroupFactory.getAllUserTasks(dateFilter)
      //                .success(function (tasks) {
      //                    console.log('success');
      //                    $scope.taskGroups = tasks.data;
      //                })
      //                .error(function (error) {
      //                    console.log(error);
      //                });
    };
  };

});

app.factory('taskGroupFactory', function($http) {
  var factory = {};
  var serviceUrl = '/_layouts/SP.TaskDashboard/WebService/TaskService.asmx';
  factory.getUserTasks = function() {
    //return $http.post(serviceUrl + '/GetMyTasks');
    return $http({
      method: 'post',
      url: serviceUrl + '/GetMyTasks',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
      }
    });
  };

  factory.getAllUserTasks = function(taskDateFilter) {

    //var serviceUrl = '/_layouts/SP.TaskDashboard/WebService/TaskService.asmx';
    //        return $http.post(serviceUrl + '/GetAllTasks', { dateFilter: taskDateFilter })
    //                    .success(function (tasks) {
    //                        return tasks;
    //                    })
    //            .error(function(errorData) {
    //                return errorData;
    //            });
    //                        return $http({
    //                            method: 'post',
    //                            url: serviceUrl + '/GetAllTasks',
    //                            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json" }
    //                        });
    return $http.post(serviceUrl + '/GetAllTasks', {
      dateFilter: taskDateFilter
    });

    //[{"WebTitle": "Press Releases","WorkflowName": "","Tasks": [{"ID": 1,"Title": "Test","WebTitle": "Press Releases","Status": "Not Started","EncodedAbsoluteUrl": "http://sukcw-vwi-sps02:2010/","ItemLink": "PressReleases/WorkflowTasks/1_.000","WorkflowLink": "","WorkflowName": "","ListId": "9F8054AD-E8C4-47B7-B9DB-24FA05853F31","DueDate": "/Date(1422316800000)/","Created": "/Date(1421327050000)/","ParentItemTitle": "","Classification": "overdue"},{"ID": 2,"Title": "Another Test","WebTitle": "Press Releases","Status": "Not Started","EncodedAbsoluteUrl": "http://sukcw-vwi-sps02:2010/","ItemLink": "PressReleases/WorkflowTasks/2_.000","WorkflowLink": "","WorkflowName": "","ListId": "9F8054AD-E8C4-47B7-B9DB-24FA05853F31","DueDate": "/Date(1422057600000)/","Created": "/Date(1421746613000)/","ParentItemTitle": "","Classification": "overdue"}]},    {"WebTitle": "Test","WorkflowName": "test apprvl workflow","Tasks": [{"ID": 29,"Title": "Please approve 05live-ego","WebTitle": "Test","Status": "Not Started","EncodedAbsoluteUrl": "http://sukcw-vwi-sps02:2010/","ItemLink": "sites/responsive/test/WorkflowTasks/29_.000","WorkflowLink": "http://sukcw-vwi-sps02:2010/sites/responsive/test/Documents/05live-ego.jpg","WorkflowName": "test apprvl workflow","ListId": "6A288BE5-51DD-43BE-B036-4B4A73BFAA5C","DueDate": null,"Created": "/Date(1426854267000)/","ParentItemTitle": " 05live-ego","Classification": "upcoming"}]}]
  };

  return factory;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="tasksApp">
  <div ng-controller="taskController">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="toggle()">Show Pending Tasks</button>
    <div ng-hide="myVar">
      <input type="radio" name="taskType" value="Self" ng-model="taskFilter" ng-change="LoadTasks(taskFilter, null)" />My Tasks
      <input type="radio" name="taskType" value="All" ng-model="taskFilter" ng-change="LoadTasks(taskFilter,list_day_option)" />All Tasks
      <span ng-hide="enableFilters">&nbsp; show tasks created in last <select ng-options="o.id as o.name for o in list_day_options.data" ng-model="list_day_option" ng-change="LoadTasks(taskFilter,list_day_option)"></select></span>

      <div class="btn-group legendWrapper" ng-init="classificationFilter='duetoday'">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="setClassificationFilter('overdue')" ng-class="{ 'active' : classificationFilter == 'overdue' }" class="taskItemOverdue btn">Overdue</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="setClassificationFilter('duetoday')" ng-class="{ 'active' : classificationFilter == 'duetoday' }" class=" taskItemDuetoday btn">Due today</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="setClassificationFilter('upcoming')" ng-class="{ 'active' : classificationFilter == 'upcoming' }" class="taskItem btn">Upcoming</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="setClassificationFilter('')" ng-class="{ 'active' : classificationFilter == '' }" class="showAllTaskItems btn">Show all</a>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-group">
        <div ng-repeat="t in taskGroups" ng-click="itemClicked($index)" class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">{{t.WebTitle  + '-' + '(' + filtered.length + ')'}}</h4>
          </div>
          <div ng-class="applyToggleClass($index)">
            <div ng-repeat="tsk in t.Tasks | filter:t.Classification=getClassificationFilter() as filtered" ng-class="applyTskClass(tsk)">
              <span>{{tsk.Title}} </span><span ng-class="applyStatusStyle(tsk)">{{tsk.Status}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Method call to getUserTasks from factory works fine, where as method call to getAllUserTasks(dateFilter) raises syntax error. No error in fiddler, shows the valid json data!! with status 200 but when I debug the script control goes into error block doesnot reach success block :( I have different ways to invoke the service method with parameter but nothing works. As you can see in the comments, feel it is to do with the way I am calling the webservice or passing the parameter to $http.post, please help.
Thanks

Comment: Is the call reaching the correct web service method?

Comment: yes, I am able to debug the webservice. If I return the hardcoded JSON object from the factory it works. but fails when I access the webservice :(

Comment: I'm confused, what do you mean "I am able to debug the webservice but it fails when I access the webservice"

Comment: If i put the webservice (.net code) in debug mode and make a call to it taskGroupFactory.getAllUserTasks(dateFilter)  I get the debug point in VS2010 and webservice returns data but in the angular script call back doesnot reach success method instead comes back to error block and error data is syntax error.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: return $http({
                            method: 'post',
                            url: serviceUrl + '/GetAllTasks',
                            params: { dateFilter: taskDateFilter },
                            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json" }
                            }); raises System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid:.

Comment: That is a .NET error, so something in your web service isn't configured properly. I know there are steps for configuring it properly when posting from a jQuery AJAX library or wrapper. A quick search turned up this result which looks like the same as yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992139/jquery-ajax-to-asp-net-asmx-web-service-throws-request-format-is-invalid-applic

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ben, the post is same issues a mine. Checked the web.config of the sharepoint webapp it already has the handlers suggested in the post. By the way I am using the angular script from a visual webpart's ascx file. The webservice (asmx) is deployed to _layouts on the sharepoint 14 hive. Any other suggestions?