# Getting error 500 while using an ajax call in a published web application hosted on iis

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, iis, asmx

I have a website that is fully working in visual studio and also in a hosted server that I bought.

But now for the sake of trying and learning IIS, I am trying to host this website in on my own computer using IIS.My website works ok except that in one of them I connect to an `asmx` service via jquery ajax

here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/WebServices/RequestHandler.asmx/GetConsultant",                         
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     data: "{id : '" + $(this).attr('data-id').toString() + "'}",
     success: function (data) {
         setTimeout(function () {     
                   modalWindowContent.find('.main').hide().html(data.d).slideDown(500);
                   }, 1000);
                        modalWindowContent.find('.main').getNiceScroll().remove();
                   },
     error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownerror) {
                   alert("something went wrong");
                   console.log(xhr.status);
                   console.log(xhr.responseText);
                   console.log(thrownerror);
                   },
     complete: function () {
                   modalWindowContent.find('.main').niceScroll({ scrollspeed: 300, mousescrollstep: 10 });
                   }
 });
```

don't mind about the code much, but as you can see, it uses an asmx service and passes it some data using json format.

it all worked well in visual studio and the hosted server, but in IIS I get error 500 saying:

> Request format is invalid: application/json; charset=UTF-8

in chrome's console

what do you think is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax to asp.net asmx web service throws Request format is invalid: application/json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992139/jquery-ajax-to-asp-net-asmx-web-service-throws-request-format-is-invalid-applic)

Comment: not sure how picky the json has to be but technically 'id' should be in quotes.

Comment: the point is this same syntax works when I am testing this application using visual studio and even when I upload it to the a host server, but it won't work when I run it under my own iis server